# How do i convert WSGIRequest to string

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

if i pass a parameter to graph_data() and convert it into string in 1st pass of program execution it take a parameter as a string but in 2nd pass it will take parameter as  please someone help me in it i want to return a proper graph for graph_data()
Note:- if i manually pass String(Stock Name) to web.dataReader() it will return graph,

index.html:-Here i want to show graph

```
<img src="{% url "showplt" %}" />
```

views.py:-
    import pandas_datareader as web

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    search = request.POST['search']

    graph_data(search)


def graph_data(request):
request_p = str(request)
ex = '.NS'
st_name = request_p + ex
print('STNAME:', st_name)
print(type(st_name))
print(type(request_p))
print(type(ex))
df = web.DataReader(st_name, data_source='yahoo', start='2019-01-01', end='2020-03-16')
print(df)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
plt.title('Close Price History')
plt.plot(df['Close'])
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Close Price in RS', fontsize=18)
buffer = io.BytesIO()
canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
canvas.draw()
pil_image = PIL.Image.frombytes("RGB", canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
pil_image.save(buffer, "PNG")
pylab.close()
response = HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type="image/png")
return response
```

urls.py:-

```
    path('showplt/', views.graph_data, name='showplt'),
```

error(Terminal):-

```
STNAME: <WSGIRequest: GET '/showplt/'>.NS
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
Not Found: /searchicon.png

STNAME: RELIANCE.NS
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
Internal Server Error: /showplt/
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: set DEBUG=True and can pls clarify error you got.

Comment: instead of passing string in st_name it passes <WSGIRequest: GET '/showplt/'>.NS   raise RemoteDataError(msg)
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/<WSGIRequest: GET '/showplt/'>.NS/history?period1=1546315200&period2=1584417599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history

Comment: try st_name.GET in DataReader

Comment: request.GET fetch you dictionary of params in your GET request

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'GET

Comment: refer this file to know about full error https://github.com/shreeshailaya/ERROR/blob/master/StProError.py

Comment: by converting to string what you are expecting, can you pls mention in your question

Answer (score 0):

As per error you mentioned, you want to get URL to put to your DataReader.

Making it str() converts WSGI request object to str, to get self absolute url path you can try :

```
request_p = request.build_absolute_uri()
```